# Typescript can't assign property after undefined check

Tags: typescript

I was reading through the MDN article for `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` and they have a little polyfill example for browsers that are a bit special. You can find it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Using_the_new_API_in_older_browsers).

I'm using Typescript and i get some weird errors. I'm new to Typescript so I'm probably missing something. This part:

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices = {};
}
```

TS tells me that the reassignment of the `mediaDevices` property is an error because it is a read-only property or constant. But if it is undefined how can it be read-only? I'm confused.

I'm using Typescript 2.3.4 and the `awesome-typescript-loader` for Webpack.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `navigator.mediaDevices` is really read-only in browsers that implement it. So TypeScript is correct in indicating that you can assign to it.

However since you are using the polyfill for old browsers where `navigator.mediaDevices` can be `undefined` and TypeScript does not seem to understand that, you can just create an untyped copy of the `navigator` to add the polyfill:

```
let navigatorCopy = navigator as any;
if (navigatorCopy.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigatorCopy.mediaDevices = {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get the same error when assigning the empty object to the copy.

Comment: Seems to be working fine at the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20navigatorCopy%20%3D%20navigator%20as%20any%3B%0D%0Aif%20(navigatorCopy.mediaDevices%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20navigatorCopy.mediaDevices%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D). Can you post your `tsconfig.json` if the issue still exists?